# Convert MySQL Query into MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've established a successful connection via MySQLi on my website. However now my search script is outdated, and being as new to this as I am I'm struggling to understand how to convert my script to mysqli.

```
    function doSearch() {
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' or description LIKE '%$searchq%' or content LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0) {
            $output = '<tr><tr>No results found.</tr></td>';
        } else {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $eName = $row['name'];
                $eDesc = $row['description'];
                $eCont = $row['content'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $elvl = $row['level'];
                $ehp = $row['hp'];

                $output .= '<tr><td><a href="http://seersvillage.com/v1.2/npc.php?id=' .$id. '" onclick="document.linkform.submit();">'.$eName.'</a></td><td>'.$eDesc.'</td><td>'.$elvl.'</td><td>'.$ehp.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    return $output;
    }
 }
```

As far as I understand, mysql_query needs to be changed am I right? Although I'm entirely unsure what else I need to change. I've tried looking at other examples, but I'm overfaced by the code.

I have my connect.php file attatched to the functions.php file, in which the code above is placed.

Some assistance would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**: Also ignore the poor scripting @ $output, although have a good laugh at it. :)

Comment: generally, mysqli is a drop-in replacement. The only REAL differences would be mysqli using `($con,$query)` type arguments instead of `($query,$con)` in mysql. But to PROPERLY convert to mysqli, you need to fundamentally rewrite ALL of your queries to exploit placeholders and prepared statements. Function names are mostly 1:1, just add an `i`.

Comment: You'll need to replace all mysql interaction functions: `mysql_query`, `mysql_fetch_array`, and `mysql_num_rows`. Not an answer since I'm not giving you the replacements, but you can easily look it up in the `mysqli` documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can find more information here http://php.net/mysqli

Comment: Thank you, I have been scanning over this. Sadly I'm still new to regular MySQL. :P So I'm still finding it difficult to learn.

Comment: Try to find a wrapper class you can see how each function works with a sample here. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Answer (score -1):

The `$connect` variable is the variable you set in you connection script.

```
<?php
    function doSearch() {
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' or description LIKE '%$searchq%' or content LIKE '%$searchq%'";
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0) {
            $output = '<tr><tr>No results found.</tr></td>';
        } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $eName = $row['name'];
                $eDesc = $row['description'];
                $eCont = $row['content'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $elvl = $row['level'];
                $ehp = $row['hp'];

                $output .= '<tr><td><a href="http://seersvillage.com/v1.2/npc.php?id=' .$id. '" onclick="document.linkform.submit();">'.$eName.'</a></td><td>'.$eDesc.'</td><td>'.$elvl.'</td><td>'.$ehp.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    return $output;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What you are doing is placing in variables instead of the raw $_POST input from users.

Comment: That's converting it and preserving all the terrifying [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Why not use placeholders? It's literally two more lines.

Answer (score -1):

if you are going to the bother of upgrading your mysql you should consider PDO as PDO supports 12 different drivers, opposed to MySQLi, which supports MySQL only.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, however.

Comment: We will only be using MySQL for the time being. I'm changing from what I had, because I was told it was insecure and was being discontinued. Security is what I need to assure here most of all.